# EF7 / Linq - "Contains" query with nested object throws Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```
public class ActivityEntry 
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CostCenterId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CostCenterId")]
    public CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
}

public class CostCenter 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query all `ActivityEntries` where the `CostCenter` has certain `ActivityIds`.

For the filter I have a List with activityIds (`filterList`). The following query throws an `System.InvalidOperationException`

[image: ErrorMessage]

> "The Sequence contains more than one element"

And I do not understand why.

```
var filterList = new List<int> {1};

var data = _db.ActivityEntry
              .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
              .Where(x => filterList.Contains(x.CostCenter.ActivityId))
              .ToList();
```

Another `WHERE` statement which doesn't use the nested object `CostCenter` is working fine.

```
.Where(x =>filterList.Contains(x.CostCenterId))
```

Do I need to use another syntax to query for the activity-Ids in `CostCenter` object?

Stack Trace:

> bei System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.<>c__DisplayClass79_0`1.b__0(IEnumerable`1 ps, IQuerySource qs)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.BindMemberExpressionCore[TResult](MemberExpression memberExpression, IQuerySource querySource, Func`3 memberBinder)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.BindMemberExpression[TResult](MemberExpression memberExpression, IQuerySource querySource, Func`3 memberBinder)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.BindMemberExpression(MemberExpression memberExpression, Action`2 memberBinder)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.RequiresMaterializationExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression memberExpression)
>      bei System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
>      bei Remotion.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperators.ContainsResultOperator.TransformExpressions(Func`2 transformation)
>      bei Remotion.Linq.QueryModel.TransformExpressions(Func`2 transformation)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.RequiresMaterializationExpressionVisitor.VisitSubQuery(SubQueryExpression subQueryExpression)
>      bei Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
>      bei Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.TransformExpressions(Func`2 transformation)
>      bei Remotion.Linq.QueryModel.TransformExpressions(Func`2 transformation)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.RequiresMaterializationExpressionVisitor.FindQuerySourcesRequiringMaterialization(QueryModel queryModel)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QueryCompilationContext.FindQuerySourcesRequiringMaterialization(EntityQueryModelVisitor queryModelVisitor, QueryModel queryModel)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<CompileQuery>b__0()
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
>      bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      bei Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
>      bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      bei zetvnext.application.Services.ReportService.GetCostCenterReportData(FilterDto filter) in C:\Source\zetvnext\src\zetvnext.application\Services\ReportService.cs:Zeile 86.
>      bei zetvnext.tests.ReportServiceTests.Test_Report_Data() in C:\Source\zetvnext\tests\zetvnext.tests\ReportServiceTests.cs:Zeile 142.

Comment: ActivityEntry doesn't seem to contain an Employee property. I doubt that's the problem, but it makes me wonder what else you're not showing... :-)

Comment: You would generally get no error when *constructing* the query above - if an error is to be generated, then usually that'll happen when you *execute* it, for example by calling `ToList()`. The specific exception quoted is one you'd likely get from `Single()`. Can you show us how the results are materialized (i.e. how the results of the query are used)?

Comment: @Gary McGill Added the employee (I try to include only the parts necessary to understand the question when I post here on SO ;-)) + Added ToList() - missed that - the exception is thrown when executing.

Comment: Can you show how the `filter` variable is declared and initialized, and a bit more of the stack trace? I'm still skeptical that `ToList()` would give that error rather than `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: @Gary Simplified the filter to List<int> and added a screenshot

Comment: When I execute the query with ToList() *before* the Where statement it works...
    _db.ActivityEntry
                          .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
                          .ToList()
                          .Where(x => filterList.Contains(x.CostCenter.ActivityId))
                          .ToList();

Comment: The reason it works that way round is that it's loading the entire table into memory and applying the `Where` clause there. That would be a bad thing to do :)

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @DavidG Yes - and I really do not want to load the entire table :-) I just posted the stack trace.

Comment: @all Thanks for the discussion and help. I've just posted an answer (bug in RC1 of EF7 :-()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an error in RC1 of EF7, fixed in RC2.

=> https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4394